# How did the nose landing gear of JetBlue Flight 292 get stuck sideways?

Tags: emergency, landing-gear, airbus, airbus-a320

The nose landing gear of the Airbus A320-200 was jammed, but the tires were perpendicular to the fuselage. How did that happen?

[image]

Comment: Slightly off topic, but serious kudos to the pilots for a [picture (video) perfect landing](http://www.maniacworld.com/JetBlue-Emergency-Landing.htm) - straight down the center line! There was surprisingly little damage to the plane, though I'm sure the nose gear got a thorough going over.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the complete [NTSB report](http://www.ntsb.gov/about/employment/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief2.aspx?ev_id=20050927X01540&ntsbno=LAX05IA312&akey=1), following is a summary of what had caused the nose landing gear (NLG) to rotate 90° on [Flight 292](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBlue_Airways_Flight_292).

> During flight, Brake Steering Control Unit (BSCU) performs<sup>1</sup>
>   cyclic tests which slightly rotates NLG from the 0° position. Due to
>   this *fatigue*, two of the four anti-rotation lugs on the NLG upper
>   support assembly fractured and separated. This allowed NLG to deviate
>   from the 0° position. Another contributing factor was BSCU system
>   logic, which prevented NLG from centering. Also contributing was the
>   lack of a procedure to attempt to reset the BSCU system under these
>   conditions.

[This website](http://www.airlinesafety.com/editorials/JetBlueLAX.htm) has some nice pictures of nose landing gear before and after the landing.

A summary of the [investigation can be found here](http://investigativereportingworkshop.org/flying-cheap/incident/20050927X01540/1/).

---

<sup>1</sup>: *BSCU has other functions too.*